Error on build Vue project by Vite in Docker on custom baseURL
I need to build Vue project into Docker that bundling by Vite
Front and backend will be deployed on the same domain
Because of that I have to set baseURL /front.
Here my files to build project
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { visualizer } from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: { transformAssetUrls }
        }),
        visualizer({ template: "list" }),
        quasar({
            sassVariables: 'src/quasar-variables.sass'
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        },
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.vue'],
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `
                    @import "@/assets/styles/global.scss";
                `,
            }
        }
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080,
    },

    base: "/front/",
})

Dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# Create Nginx server
FROM nginx:1.24.0-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build /var/www/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

nginx.conf
types {
    application/javascript js;
    text/javascript js;
}

server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}

All I found about this task said me that my file is correct.
One time I gave up and asked GPT, but he gave the same output.
But I'm get this error:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.


I wrote an answer some time ago related to the mime type checking. Does this help? disable chrome strict MIME type checking on local dev. You likely just have a 404 error because the script's URL is wrong. Check the network tab of your browser developer tools, compare to the real URL the file is in and correct the baseURL is my guess.
